# IntelliJ: Iterate over focused word

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA adequately highlights the word and its occurrences where the cursor position sits. I would like to know if shortcuts for navigating these highlighted words exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to find the word at caret, and then use <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to navigate between the occurrences.
[[source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/finding-word-at-caret.html)]